# When I run my Java program which has a Scanner object, the Windows Wait Cursor is always there. How can I change this?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a Java game in which you play Blackjack, and I use a Scanner to take input for things like "hit" and "stay." When I run it, the [Windows wait cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_wait_cursor) shows up and doesn't go away until I close the program. I tried to use Scanner's close() method, but that throws an exception.

here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public  class CardGame {

    public static ArrayList<Card> dealIn(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

        Card a = new Card();
        Card b = new Card();

        hand.add(a);

        while (hand.size() < 2) {
            if (!b.equals(a)) {
                hand.add(b);
            } else
                dealIn(hand);
        }
        return hand;
    }

    public static int calcScore(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

        int sum = 0;
        int aces = 0;

        for (Card c : hand) {
            if (c.getCardValue().getFace().equals("A")) {
                aces++;
            } else {
                sum += c.getCardValue().getNumeric();
            }
        }
        while (aces > 0) {
            aces--;
            if (sum <= 10) {
                sum += 11;
            } else {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack!\n");
        ArrayList<Card> playerhand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        ArrayList<Card> dealerhand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        dealIn(playerhand);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Card a = new Card();
            if ((!playerhand.contains(a)) && (!dealerhand.contains(a))) {
                dealerhand.add(a);
            }
        }

        // System.out.println("DEALER HAND: [hidden]" + " and " +
        // dealerhand.get(1));
        System.out.println("TEST DEALER HAND: " + dealerhand);
        System.out.println("Your hand: " + playerhand);

        while (!isBusted(playerhand)) {
            System.out.println("Your score is " + calcScore(playerhand) + ". Hit or stay?");
            String hOrS = in.nextLine();

            if (hOrS.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {

                hit(playerhand);
                System.out.println(playerhand);

                if (isBusted(playerhand)) {
                    System.out.println("Your score is " + calcScore(playerhand) + "! YOU LOSE");
                    break;
                }
                // System.out.println(playerhand);

            }
            if (hOrS.equalsIgnoreCase("stay")) {

                while (calcScore(dealerhand) <= 17) {
                    Card n = new Card();
                    if (!dealerhand.contains(n)) {
                        dealerhand.add(n);
                        // System.out.println(dealerhand);
                    }
                }

            }

            if (isBusted(dealerhand) || (!isBusted(playerhand) && (calcScore(playerhand) > calcScore(dealerhand)))) {
                System.out.println("DEALER HAND: " + dealerhand);
                System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + playerhand);
                System.out.println("YOU WIN");
                // break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(dealerhand);
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Wait cursor usually suggest that your application is busy which mostly happens when you have infinite loop. But in this case in each iteration flow of control should be stopped at `in.nextLine()` so maybe you are entering into infinite loop at `calcScore(playerhand)` method. Does it also contain some loop?

Comment: Can't say more without having [mcve].

Comment: OT but you need to check the `readLine()` result for null.

Comment: OK I've added the entire class

Comment: @EJP It is `Scanner#nextLine` not `readLine` so it can't return `null`. If there is no more data to read NoSuchElementException should be thrown.

Comment: @Derry Can we also see rest of classes needed to actually run this application? like `Card` class (and if there are others which Card requires)? Also it doesn't look like you posted whole `CardGame` class (it misses at least two `}` and possibly some code before them).

Comment: I've fixed the code now

Comment: I formatted your code, but you removed `isBusted` nor `hit` methods. To get any help you need to post code which we will be able to use to reproduce your problem. This means we need to be able to run it which also involves compiling, but we can't compile it if there are methods missing or if it you are not posting classes which are also needed like `Card`.